# replace NA with nothing in R changes variable types to categorical

Tags: r, replace, na

Is there anyway without converting to char to replace NA with blank or nothing?
I used

```
data_model <- sapply(data_model, as.character)
data_model[is.na(data_model)] <- " "
data_model=data.table(data_model)
```

however it changes all the columns' types to categorical.
I want to save the data set and use it in sas it does not understand NA.

Comment: It is quite probable that you have no need of making any changes to the `NA`s in order to move the data to SAS.  But we would need to understand how you intend to move the data to SAS. If you will be exporting from R to csv, you can use `write.csv(..., na = "")`, for example.  SAS will likely read the empty character as a missing value (at least I think it will, it's been a while).  But in principle, the exporting function is probably the best place to handle this task.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat belated (and shameless self-promotion) from [The R Primer](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/1439862060/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=1439862060&linkCode=as2&tag=shortcoursein-21) on how to export a data frame to SAS. It should automatically correctly handle your `NA`s:

First you can use the `foreign` package to export the data frame as a SAS xport dataset. Here, I'll just export the `trees` data frame.

```
library(foreign)
data(trees)
write.foreign(trees, datafile = "toSAS.dat",
              codefile="toSAS.sas", package="SAS")
```

This gives you two files, `toSAS.dat` and `toSAS.sas`. It is easy to get the data into SAS since the codefile `toSAS.sas` contains a SAS script that can be read and interpreted directly by SAS and reads the data in `toSAS.dat`.